# Using mean values for principal component analysis (morphological data)

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis

I have a potentially dumb question that I've been having a hard time find an answer to.

About my data:
I am working with a set of morphological data (external cranial measurements of bats), using museum specimens. I am looking to reduce my variables into principal components so I can ask questions about how morphology can predict certain ecological variables (such as diet) across a bunch of different species. For each species, I measured up to 11 individuals. Running my analyses using R.

I have run a principal component analysis on the entire dataset (all 295 data points, which means up to 11 rows of data per species). My question is, would it be valid for me to combine my up to 11 observations for each variable into an average (which would mean only one row per species), and use that for the principal component analysis? My thought is it would make it easier to interpret my principal component outputs (such as identifying where each species falls along each PC).

Thanks!

Comment: No, I don't recommend you to do within-group averaging and using then just 11 cases (the means for PCA). Rather, _remove effect_ of the species heterogeneity on every your variable (measurement) by means of one-way ANOVA (dependent is the measurement, factor is "species" categorical variable with 11 levels). Save residuals. These are the variables to input in PCA.

Comment: (cont.) By virtue of that you've removed the effect of species different means on the eogenvectors of PCA: you actually are superimposing all the means in point 0. Do PCA based on correlations (i.e., standardize the variables (residuals) because your measurements were of very different variances, I suppose.

Comment: Because the 11 multivariate means can be seen as data points, you can compute component scores for those 11 "cases" as you will do for the 295 cases; ah, you simply could add those 11 means into the PCA (295+11 cases in all) and get the scores. Then you could set the species mean location to those 11 scores location: here you are ready to compare species (by ANOVA or t-tests or else) now on the extracted components.

Comment: Before doing all the above one would check if correlation matrices of the 11 species are reasinably similar to warrant common PCA on the combined sample of cases. But I think you could omit that because bats are enough close species and cranial correlations are expected to be similar.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the responses. I'd like to clarify though, I have more than 11 species worth of data (actually 37 species). The 11 is the number of individuals measured from each species.